# Download video to PC from Sony DCR-DVD110E

Tags: video

Hello Wonderful Helpful People,

I do apologize if this question is not suitable for this forum.

I'm trying to download video from the mini-dvd on a Sony DCR-DVD110E to my PC. After hooking up the camera to the computer using a USB cable I choose the option on the Sony screen entitled **USB Connect** with the little disc icon next to it.

Then a DVD-ROM icon with the words **CD Drive(E:)** pop up on my machine. I then click on that and I get a message saying **E:/ is not accesible.**

I don't have a memory stick or a mini-DVD reader.

My question is:

**How can I download video from my camera to my PC?**

All help appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much googling I've figured it out:

1. Finalize the mini-DVD on the Sony Camera. (Look in the menu for options to do this).
2. Insert the mini-DVD into the DVD drive on your machine.

Et Voila!